# What's the -alhF flag in ls?

Tags: command-line, ls, options

What is the `-alhF` flag in `ls`? I can't find it in the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man ls`:

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

   -h, --human-readable
          with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

   -l     use a long listing format
```

The command `ls -alhF` is equivalent to `ls -a -l -h -F`

The ability to combine command line arguments like this is defined by  POSIX.

> Options that do not require arguments can be grouped after a hyphen, so, for example, -lst is equivalent to -t -l -s.

Comment: O!  Nowhere explained on the Internet!  So, it is the combination of the 4 commands as defined in your answer, yes?

Comment: @MariaS. yes, that is what my answer explicitly says.

Comment: Casey, why do I see a 'yesterday' next to 'casey' above?  And why did the question I asked is now phrased differently?

Comment: @MariaS. your question was edited by others to increase its clarity and make it easier for others to find it.

Comment: It now sounds, like a beginner's question said by an expert.  I wouldn't pick-up on the word 'flag' and would think it has to do with something else, if I was searching for an answer to my question.  Anyway, thank you very much...